# ArangoDB: how can I show the path id in all the edges that make up this path

Tags: arangodb

after calculating a path traversal in ArangoDB I want to use the data in downstream applications. down there I need to reconcile all edges that make up the path in question. So ideally the paths as an id and this id is also present in the edges involved and shows up in the resulting json.

the current json for path documents holds the path with no further identification and assembles all edge and vertice information under it. When I try to convert the json in Power Query the edge information is lost.

any help is higly appreciated

BB